# Maintain specific string portions when matching regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

Consider the following toy example:

```
a <- c(rep(1,3))
b <- c(rep("b", 3))
names <- c("2019 Report", "XYZ Report", "2018 Report")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, names))
```

I want to modify the strings in the `names` column, but only for names which contain a year:

```
names_desired <- c("2019 Good Report", "XYZ Report", "2018 Good Report")
df_target <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, names, names_desired))
```

There are plenty of ways to do this by filtering out non-year containing names, for example (ordering irrelevant):

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(names, "[:digit:]") == FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(names_desired = names) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              filter(str_detect(names, "[:digit:]") == TRUE) %>% 
              mutate(names_desired = str_replace(names, "Report", "Good Report")))
```

What I want though is a way to match names with something regex-ish, like this (*does not work*):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(names_desired = str_replace(names, "[:digit:]{4} Report", "[:digit:]{4} Good Report"))
```

Ideally that `"[:digit:]{4}"` would give back the digits it matched on, bu of course it does not.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to capture as a group (`(...)`) and then replace with the backreferences (`\\1`, `\\2` - based on the order of captured groups)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(names_desired = str_replace(names, '(\\d{4}) (Report)', '\\1 Good \\2'))
df
#    a b       names    names_desired
#1 1 b 2019 Report 2019 Good Report
#2 1 b  XYZ Report       XYZ Report
#3 1 b 2018 Report 2018 Good Report
```

In this case, 'Report' is fixed so we need to only capture a single group

```
df %>%
   mutate(names_desired = str_replace(names, '(\\d{4}) Report', '\\1 Good Report'))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sub("(\\d{4}) (Report)", "\\1 Good \\2", df$names)
#[1] "2019 Good Report" "XYZ Report"       "2018 Good Report"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b, names)
```

Comment: Excellent - I'll accept this when the embargo is up.  In the meantime could you edit it to ```'\\1 Good \\2'``` since there's only two backreferences?  Can't change one character in an edit...